# Extracting information from a c++ file

Tags: c++, parsing

i know this question must be a little bit unclear but i'm going to try my best to explain my needs.

first, i'm an apprentice developer since 1 year now, i'm on an internship and my boss want me to create a documentation generator based on code.

**documentation generator based on code ?**

the documentation generator is a program that will read a c++ file, and from this c++ file, retrieve a maximum of information including declared variables and functions and display them in a human readable format (a table).

**Example :**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int returnANumber(int argNumber)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = argNumber;
    return argNumber;
}

int main()
{
    returnANumber(70);

    return 0;
}
```

this is a c++ file example that the program will read, and retrieve all the informations, in this case function's name(returnANumber), variable(i), the using directive(iostream).

As a first approach, i wanted to use REGEX, and match for example :

```
data-type word ( data-type word);
```

with a function declaration, but there are so many cases to manage, for example in the declaration of a method in a static class... :

```
data-type static word (data-type word);
```

here the REGEXs are a very hard solution, and i worder if there is other solutions to use ? any help ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use an existing tool rather than re-inventing the wheel ?

Comment: @PaulR thanks for your reply, as i said am new, what existing tools do you mean?

Comment: e.g. Doxygen http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/ might be what you are looking for

Comment: ahh you talking about doxygen, No i can't use it because my boss wants one from scratch

Comment: Regular expressions are really bad for complex C++ declarations. You might want to read about [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [LLVM](http://www.llvm.org/).

Comment: Back in my day we sent interns to fetch coffee. At least that achieved something useful.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg any good articles about clang and llvm?

Comment: You could try to run Clang to emit the AST of the program and build some kind of structured data around that.

Comment: @KerrekSB i'm a very special intern :D

Comment: With all due respect to your boss, he's an idiot if he thinks that the only way to do things is to write everything from scratch.

Comment: @PaulR: It's also a very special boss!

Comment: @PaulR he is i tried to convince him...

Comment: guys any help on clang ?

Comment: If one interprets "you have to write a tool from scratch" narrowly, technically you can't use Clang, either.  So exactly what are you allowed/required to do?

Comment: FWIW, I believe Doxygen now uses Clang internally for C++.

Comment: You must construct your own computer from raw mineral ore, and generate your own electricity. Good luck.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: To do that, you must construct additional pylons.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem as stated appears to require that you read a C++ source file by itself, and extract documentation. In general, this will be impossible: C++ allows macros, which can in effect make arbitrary edits to the original text to produce valid C++ source code. C++ also allows #include directives, which pick up additional information needed to accurately interpret types. In the face of these, you cannot extract good information.

So you have two choices:

- "Parse" individual files and extract what you can in face of these problems. I use the word "parse" sloppily here, because the program source by itself isn't valid C++ in the presence of macros and includes. In this case, a regex will probably do about as well as you can hope. Don't expect it to do well; C++ is a very difficult language to parse and regexes don't handle context-free parsing, so the holes in this scheme will be endless and painful. [Doxygen uses as a default "bad parsing" to do this kind of "parse"ing for many languages, see additional note below] (If you *insist* on this path, our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit might be helpful: it can be configured to  parse source files as a series of valid language substrings, making it possible to read not-well-formed files. It will be difficult to get type information even with this).
- **Parse** the individual files the way a compiler would, using full preprocessing capabilities to get the program text the way the compiler really sees it. This requires the tools to process all the preprocessor directives, including any (commonly) found on the compiler command line. Compilers build full symbol tables, which contain IMHO exactly the information you want to extract. For this, you need something that has a full compiler front end. You don't have the energy to build one yourself.

Some choices for the latter are:

- Clang/LLVM
- Edison Design Group (EDG) C++ front end
- Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit.
- GCC (probably the derived tool GCCXML)

Setting up each of these, and extracting the information you want, is a pretty big exercise. To use them directly, you have to know a lot about each tool, and about compiler technology in general (parsing, symbol tables) and then you have to custom-code something in the ecosystem these tools offer internally. Expect this to take you a long time to learn if you are unfamiliar with them.

Clang/LLVM is OSS, and coded in C++. I don't know how well it handles Microsoft dialects of C++. My understanding is that Doxygen uses Clang to process C++ source code these days; that might be the easiest way to get this information especially if all you want is "some documentatoin" already preformatted. But, that violates your "build a tool from scratch" dictum.

EDG is a commercial front end that is widely used in many production C++ compilers. It is available for research (maybe what you are doing can be classified as that, but if you are commercial outfit I doubt it); I think it is coded in C.

DMS is commercial, but has research license options; coding is done in combination of domain specific languages involving BNF, attribute grammars and a parallel programming language PARLANSE. DMS handles GCC and MS dialects of C++ up through C++11 and most of C++14.

GCC is coded in C, but really, really wants to be compiler and will resist your efforts to bend it to your purposes. However, other folks have been here before with GCC and have built GCCXML on top that extracts at least some of the information you want as an XML file; that might be your best bet if you want to get the information easily in a form you can manipulate.